Failed to pull image from private GHCR repo
I have a private GitHub repo where i use a GitHub action workflow to automatically push a docker image to my GHCR repo.
This is the GitHub action workflow:
name: Create and publish a Docker image

# Configures this workflow to run every time a change is pushed to the branch called `release`.
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
      branches: ["main"]

# Defines two custom environment variables for the workflow. These are used for the Container registry domain, and a name for the Docker image that this workflow builds.
env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

# There is a single job in this workflow. It's configured to run on the latest available version of Ubuntu.
jobs:

    build-and-push-image-dev:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      if: github.ref_name != 'main'
  
      # Sets the permissions granted to the `GITHUB_TOKEN` for the actions in this job.
      permissions:
        contents: read
        packages: write
        
      steps:
  
        - name: Checkout repository
          uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: Set up QEMU
          uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3

        - name: Set up Docker Buildx
          uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
  
        # Uses the `docker/login-action` action to log in to the Container registry registry using the account and password that will publish the packages. Once published, the packages are scoped to the account defined here.
        - name: Log in to the Container registry
          uses: docker/login-action@v3
          with:
            registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
            username: ${{ github.actor }}
            password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  
        # This step uses the `docker/build-push-action` action to build the image, based on your repository's `Dockerfile`. If the build succeeds, it pushes the image to GitHub Packages.
        # It uses the `context` parameter to define the build's context as the set of files located in the specified path. For more information, see "[Usage](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#usage)" in the README of the `docker/build-push-action` repository.
        # It uses the `tags` and `labels` parameters to tag and label the image with the output from the "meta" step.
        - name: Build and push Docker image
          uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
          with:
            context: .
            push: true
            platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
            tags: "${{env.REGISTRY}}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:dev"

    build-and-push-image-main:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      if: github.ref_name == 'main'
    
      # Sets the permissions granted to the `GITHUB_TOKEN` for the actions in this job.
      permissions:
        contents: read
        packages: write
        
      steps:
    
        - name: Checkout repository
          uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: Set up QEMU
          uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
          
        - name: Set up Docker Buildx
          uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
    
        # Uses the `docker/login-action` action to log in to the Container registry registry using the account and password that will publish the packages. Once published, the packages are scoped to the account defined here.
        - name: Log in to the Container registry
          uses: docker/login-action@v3
          with:
            registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
            username: ${{ github.actor }}
            password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    
        # This step uses the `docker/build-push-action` action to build the image, based on your repository's `Dockerfile`. If the build succeeds, it pushes the image to GitHub Packages.
        # It uses the `context` parameter to define the build's context as the set of files located in the specified path. For more information, see "[Usage](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#usage)" in the README of the `docker/build-push-action` repository.
        # It uses the `tags` and `labels` parameters to tag and label the image with the output from the "meta" step.
        - name: Build and push Docker image
          uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
          with:
            context: .
            push: true
            platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
            tags: "${{env.REGISTRY}}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:prod"

I am trying to pull this image from an Oracle Linux server. This is only working if i pull it from root user. If i try to pull it from any other user, i get the error below:
Error response from daemon: Head "https://ghcr.io/v2/mervinhemaraju/zeus/manifests/prod": unauthorized

I ran the command echo "xxx" | docker login ghcr.io -u myusername --password-stdin before pulling the image and i get the login succeeded from each user. Bu the image pull works just for root user.
In the packages settings, I did add myself as admin and also the repo itself as admin.
I have another repo that has the same configurations and workflows (except that it is a public repo) and I am able to pull its image from any users.
Can someone help me out ?

Why are you using actor as the user name?

Github.actor here has my username

Oh if you are getting an error locally, remove things related to your action. Ensure you have logged in

Yes i am logged in because i can pull images from other GHCR repo
